# Заменить определенные элементы в html файле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! Нужен совет, каким образом лучше всего реализовать решение такой задачи:

Есть html файл, с большим количеством таблиц, ссылок, картинок итд итп

Допустим я хочу заменить все ссылки из этого файла такого вида (только выделенную жирным часть):

```
href="http://primer.ru/?of=disp-hv4b4-08&auto-token=[% anketa.a907.q907%]#/document/184/">
```

на такую:

```
href="http://primer.ru/?of=disp-hv4b4-08&auto-token=[[=Contact.f_xssguid;]]#/document/184/">
```

Как этого проще всего добиться? Использовать регулярные выражения или ещё каким нибудь образом? Я понимаю, что это можно всё сделать через ctrl + h, но дело в том, что менять нужно не только ссылки но и адреса к картинкам и много чего ещё, что отнимает много времени, а хочется просто нажать на кнопку и что бы все изменения сразу были внесены.

Comment: Через регулярное выражение и функцию `replace`

Comment: И если это у вас атрибуты в элементах, то лучше брать не весь документ, а по отдельности атрибуты нужных элементов